# How Do I Set Z-Index in an ItemsControl with a Data Binding?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

There are several answers to this but none of them work for UWP, only WPF.  I have a custom ItemsControl that dynamically places its children in an unusual pattern based on properties within the child's respective view model.  Items partially overlap and I need to ensure the selected item is not hidden beneath any other items.  But I cannot figure out how to bind a value to the Grid's Z-index.

```
<ItemsControl Name="myItemsControl" ItemsSource="{x:Bind PageViewModel.myCollectionOfMyViewModel}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
   <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="myTransform" />
   </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <Grid />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodel:MyViewModel">
          <Grid Name="ItemGrid" Canvas.ZIndex="{x:Bind SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemToZindexConverter}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
               <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform Rotation="{Binding ItemIdxNum, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ItemIdxToRotationAngleConverter}}"
                                                TranslateX="{Binding ItemIdxNum, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ItemIdxToXPosConverter}}"
                                                TranslateY="{Binding ItemIdxNum, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ItemIdxToYPosConverter}}"
                                                ScaleX="{x:Bind SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemBoolToScaleConverter}}"
                                                ScaleY="{x:Bind SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemBoolToScaleConverter}}"
                                                />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                      <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ItemName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>                                
           </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

The Canvas.Zindex in there does not throw a build error but it doesn't work.  Searching here and elsewhere it seems I need to target the ItemsControl's ContentPresenter instead of the child elements.  But I don't know how to go about this. All the examples are for WPF and use Style triggers target type which aren't available in UWP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a typo. It's capital `I` in `ZIndex`.

```
Canvas.ZIndex="..." <!-- right -->

Canvas.Zindex="..." <!-- wrong -->
```

**Update**

`ItemsControl` will wrap all your items with a `ContentPresenter`, but you can override that functionality by creating your own version. Use this instead of `ItemsControl`:

```
public class MyItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return ItemTemplate?.LoadContent() ?? base.GetContainerForItemOverride();
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        ((FrameworkElement) element).DataContext = item;
    }
}
```

And your xaml can use this by just switching out the root level tag to `MyItemsControl`

```
 <local:MyItemsControl Name="myItemsControl"
                        ItemsSource="{x:Bind PageViewModel.myCollectionOfMyViewModel}"
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="myTransform" />
    </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodel:MyViewModel">
            <Grid Name="ItemGrid"
                    Canvas.ZIndex="{x:Bind SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemToZindexConverter}}"
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform Rotation="{Binding ItemIdxNum, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ItemIdxToRotationAngleConverter}}"
                                        TranslateX="{Binding ItemIdxNum, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ItemIdxToXPosConverter}}"
                                        TranslateY="{Binding ItemIdxNum, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ItemIdxToYPosConverter}}"
                                        ScaleX="{x:Bind SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemBoolToScaleConverter}}"
                                        ScaleY="{x:Bind SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemBoolToScaleConverter}}" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ItemName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</local:MyItemsControl>
```

Comment: The typo was only here, my mistake I edited the post with a correction.  As I said it builds fine.  In fact it works fine if I manually add items.  But doing an ItemsSource binding with a data template it does not work.

Comment: Here is an example of someone else with the same problem.  But as I mentioned the solution provided is for WPF and doesn't apply to UWP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637903/how-to-overlay-items-in-stackpanel-or-listview/39640662

Comment: {Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key SelectedItemBoolToZindexConverter [Line: 454 Position: 129]
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate.LoadContent()
   at Tilted.CustomControls.MyItemsControl.GetContainerForItemOverride()}

Comment: @SeanO'Neil, that's a different problem now. Can you try reverting to `{Binding}` instead of `{x:Bind}`? Let me know what happens...

Comment: I actually already tried that.  The first error I copied and pasted is from x:Bind.  The screenshot is from Binding.

Comment: `Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  HResult=0x802B000A
  Message=The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key SelectedItemBoolToZindexConverter [Line: 454 Position: 129]
  Source=
  StackTrace:
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate.LoadContent()
   at Tilted.CustomControls.MyItemsControl.GetContainerForItemOverride() in C:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Tilted\Tilted\CustomControls\MyItemsControl.cs:line 15`

Comment: I tried it on my machine on a blank application and the resources loaded fine. I understand your app is going to be more advanced than the blank app, but it could be the way you've setup your resources. They may not actually be available at the point you call `LoadContent()`. Start with the blank app and work from there.

Comment: I'll troubleshoot it and check the load timing like you suggested.  If it helps I'm running VS 2017 with latest updates.

Comment: I took out the type converter, bound it to an int property, and it works now!  Thanks!  My XAML code is showing blue squiggly lines everywhere now I don't know why but the designer loads and everything builds and deploys fine.